# Typing: declaring classmethod-like decorators

Tags: python, mypy, class-method, python-typing

mypy has the binding semantics for `@classmethod` baked into it (in fact from looking at the source code I believe it is hard-coded for `builtins.classmethod`) so this works:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import Any


class Foo:
    def __init__(self, x: Any) -> None:
        self.x = x

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, x: Any) -> Foo:
        return cls(x)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo = Foo.create(1)
    print(foo)
```

```
$ mypy a0.py
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

But say, for valid reasons, I have a decorator that has `classmethod`-like binding behavior on the first argument (expecting it to be a class).  To give a simple example that approximates `classmethod` itself:

```py
class myclassmethod:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def __get__(self, obj, cls):
        return partial(self.func, cls)


class Foo:
    def __init__(self, x: Any) -> None:
        self.x = x

    @myclassmethod
    def create(cls, x: Any) -> Foo:
        return cls(x)
```

Unsurprisingly this does not check out; mypy assumes the first argument is bound to a `Foo` instance, and errors out at the call site of `cls(x)`:

```
$ mypy a1.py
a1.py:20: error: "Foo" not callable
```

If I try to explicitly give the "cls" a type in contradicts the default `bind_self` behavior for instance methods:

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, x: Any) -> None:
        self.x = x

    @myclassmethod
    def create(cls: Type[Foo], x: Any) -> Foo:
        return cls(x)
```

```
$ mypy a2.py 
a2.py:19: error: The erased type of self "Type[a2.Foo]" is not a supertype of its class "a2.Foo"
```

The only workaround I've found is to not declare the type of `cls` in the signature, but instead to cast it at the call site:

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, x: Any) -> None:
        self.x = x

    @myclassmethod
    def create(cls, x: Any) -> Foo:
        return cast(Type[Foo], cls)(x)
```

This passes as far as type checking goes, but is a little inconvenient and error-prone since this will have to be done by any user of `@myclassmethod`.

I see that there is a `is_classmethod` argument to mypy's `bind_self`, but this is really only applied in the *specific* case of functions decorated with `builtins.classmethod`.  Subclassing `classmethod` doesn't help either (I guess mypy is making the conservative assumption that a subclass of `classmethod` may have arbitrary behavior).

I just wonder if there's a way, without digging deep into mypy internals, to explicitly override the self-binding behavior of functions that are arguments to a decorator.